# supporting REFERENCES threading locally

Tags: imap

I see the following imap server only provides ORDEREDSUBJECT threading. Does it mean that REFERENCES threading is not supported?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.gmx.com:993
...
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ENABLE ID IDLE LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- MOVE NAMESPACE SASL-IR SORT SPECIAL-USE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] IMAP server ready H migmx101 26.3 IMAP-1MT9Jn-1q3sf109Lr-00UWnW
```

If REFERENCES threading is not supported on the server, how can I do so locally (python solution preferred) given that I can download the messages in RFC 822 format using imapclient?

https://imapclient.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: Download the Message-ID, References, and In-Reply-To header to every message, and store them.  Follow the definition in the RFCs, or for a summary: http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: JWZ also documents his algorithm for threading.  It’s quite old, and maybe overkill for what you’re doing: https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `CAPABILITY` response code is the way how IMAP servers announce what they support. If a server tells you that it only does `THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT`, then you simply do not have any other server-side threading algorithms at your disposal. Note, however, that the capabilities can change, especially after a `LOGIN`. It would be a strange server to offer different threading implementations based on users' credentials :), but it's "possible".

Since you want a threading algorithm that doesn't suck and since the server won't help you here that much, the only way is replicating the functionality in your client. In that case I recommend implementing an algorithm that's called [`THREAD=REFS`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-morg-inthread-01#section-4) because it addresses several problems of `THREAD=REFERENCES` (e.g., e-mails with generic subjects like "info" being mixed together, or old threads with fresh arrivals getting silently ignored).

Comment: Is there a python implementation of the THREAD=REFS  algorithm?